# Yii urlmanager

Tags: yii

Хотелось бы использовать такой вариант URLов:

> site.ru/name-of-url-page-ID.html
>
> site.ru/%name%-page-%id%.html

для этого я исполюзую в nginx

> rewrite  ^/(.*)-page-(.*).html$ 
> /index.php?r=page/view&id=$2&url=$1
> last;

Да все работает, но как сделать такое через urlmanager чтобы можно было вызывать createUrl() передавая id (=5) и name (=blablabla) и получалось

> site.ru/blablabla-page-5.html

так же интересует, как запретить заходить в будущем на

> /index.php?r=page/view&id=5&url=blablabla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В конфиге:

```
'urlManager' => array(
    'urlFormat' => 'path',
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'urlSuffix' => '.html'
    'rules' => array(
        '<uri:[\w-]+>-page-<id:\d+>' => 'controllerName/actionName'
    ),
),
```

В nginx ничего настраивать не нужно

В экшене теперь можно юзать:

```
$id = Yii::app()->request->getParam('id');
$url = Yii::app()->request->getParam('url');
```

Comment: А как делать createUrl() грамотно для такого пути?

Comment: <?=Yii::app()->createUrl('controllerName/actionName', array('url' => $url, 'id' => $id));?>

Comment: получается путь /controllerName/actionName/url/blablabla/id/5

А точно должно сработать правило в rules и createUrl() ?

Comment: Точно. Не первый день его использую. Смотри нет ли ошибок, возможно есть роут, который также подходит, из-за чего происходит неправильное формирование урла.

Comment: #Проблема была в роуте. Оказывается нужно указывать модуль тоже:
'admin/controller/action'